# Create matplotlib figure from rgb array

Tags: image, matplotlib

I have a png image I would like to make into a matplotlib Figure. I am able to make the png image into matplotlib.image.AxesImage object by doing the following (though there's probably a better way):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rgba2rgb(rgba, background=(255,255,255)):
    row, col, ch = rgba.shape

    if ch == 3:
        return rgba

    assert ch == 4, 'RGBA image has 4 channels.'

    rgb = np.zeros( (row, col, 3), dtype='float32' )
    r, g, b, a = rgba[:,:,0], rgba[:,:,1], rgba[:,:,2], rgba[:,:,3]

    a = np.asarray( a, dtype='float32' )/255

    R, G, B = background

    rgb[:,:,0] = r * a + (1.0 - a) * R
    rgb[:,:,1] = g * a + (1.0 - a) * G
    rgb[:,:,2] = b * a + (1.0 - a) * B

    return np.asarray( rgb, dtype='uint8' )

img = Image.open('image.png')
rgba_arr = np.array(img)
rgb_array = rgba2rgb(rgba_arr)
plt_img = plt.imshow(rgb_array, aspect='auto')
```

Again, the main problem I'm having is that the result of plt.imshow is a matplotlib.image.AxesImage rather than a matplotlib Figure. How can I make this a figure? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-insert-an-image-a-picture-or-a-photo-in-a-matplotlib-figure/

Comment: That will do! Thanks :)